# Submiting a form with jQuery Confirm Dialog Replacement

Tags: jquery

I'm using this [jQuery Confirm Dialog Replacement](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/) script for regular text links. But I would like to use it also when submiting a form and I'm having problems.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>A jQuery Confirm Dialog Replacement with CSS3 | Tutorialzine Demo</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum&amp;subset=latin'       rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <form action="test.php" method="post" id="reg">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="confirm" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.confirm').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();


    $.confirm({
        'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It     cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
        'buttons'   : {
            'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                    $("#reg").submit();
                }
            },
            'No'    : {
                'class' : 'gray',
                'action': function(){}  
            }
        }
    });

});

});
```

Why is this not working? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Can you define "not working"?

Comment: is it executing the submit and not working or not even getting there?

Comment: sorry, wasn't specific enough: when I click the Submit button, the confirm dialog appears. Then if I click Yes on this dialog, the dialog disappears, but the form does not get submitet.

Comment: if it's the only form on the page, try `$("form").submit();` instead of referring to the ID `$("#reg")`. `PreventDefault` may be causing an issue.  Try removing it and instead at the close of `$('.confirm').click()` put `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated JS to try, in case my comment was confusing.

TRY 1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.confirm').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();


    $.confirm({
        'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It     cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
        'buttons'   : {
            'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                    $("form").submit();
                }
            },
            'No'    : {
                'class' : 'gray',
                'action': function(){}  
            }
        }
    });
});

});
```

TRY 2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.confirm').click(function(e){
    // e.preventDefault();


    $.confirm({
        'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It     cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
        'buttons'   : {
            'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                    $("#reg").submit();
                }
            },
            'No'    : {
                'class' : 'gray',
                'action': function(){}  
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Nope, not working. If I put `alert('test');` instead of `$("#reg").submit();`, the alert box DOES show up. I can also get the form properties displayed in an alert box with `alert($("#reg").attr('method'));`, but I can not get it to submit.

Comment: Well I'm truly puzzled. Nothing in your HTML code, the plugin code or your JS code is broken. I've tested myself, and encounter the same problem (multiple browsers).  One alternative, not ideal, would be to use $.post() or $.get(), serialize the data and submit via AJAX.

Comment: That is an option, that I would like to avoid. For now I'm going to use this solution: [link](http://www.jensbits.com/2009/08/10/modal-confirmation-dialog-on-form-submit-javascript-jquery-ui-and-thickbox-varieties/) (jQuery UI dialog).

Of course if someone finds a solution for the above problem, I would really appreciate!